# What does Integer value mean in android:theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

When I add themes I use syntax

```
android:theme="@android:style/Something"
```

I see that many use Integer value after @android. For example

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:01030006"
    android:name=".SomeActivity">
```

Intellisense does not show any Integer values for themes.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: This is the same project from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203829/android-class-naming-with-symbol. Can this number be a sign of compiler naming? Or the sign that this is decompiled project (reverse engineering)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a way to directly use [`Theme_NoTitleBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoTitleBar). As you know, in order to access any kind of resource from Java code, android assigns a integer to each resource (which is a constant in the `R` class). I guess that, if you use `@android:01030006` directly, it could *improve* the parsing process... however I don't think there's a great improvement doing it that way.

Comment: Actually I thought of that and looked into my project's R class and could not find that integer!!! Do you know in which R class it's located then?

Comment: Another Q: where did you find the meaning of that code? Thanks

Comment: Dude, I already gave you the link. The code is there. Of course, it's not your `R` class, but the `android.R` class.

Comment: LOL sorry, I did not recognize Theme_NoTitleBar as link. I thought it was just the way stackoverflow colors the code :)). Thanks