# Android or Java class naming with $ symbol

Tags: java, android

I'm reviewing a certain project and I see that there are many classes with the same name, but with a dollar ($) symbol at the end + increasing number. For example

```
Class.java
Class$1.java
Class$2.java
Class$n.java
OtherClass.java
OtherClass$1.java
OtherClass$n.java
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Curious..I have never seen this!

Comment: I have seen it only with classes having child classes or obfuscated codes.

Comment: Hmmmm you're right. It seems that this is decompiled project. I tried the same with my project, and got these symbols. Can someone confirm this so I can close the topic??

Comment: Isn't title sholud also include `Java`? because I don't think it's only specifiec to `Android`.

Comment: I've added it. I wasn't sure if this was Android-only thing ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK if it's has number it's an anonymous inner class, if it has a name after $ sign it means just inner class.
**Edit**:
More about how compiler handles you can see [here](http://www.retrologic.com/innerclasses.doc7.html)

Comment: You're right that it is normally the number of anonymous inner classes, but Av $ doesn't necessarily mean an inner class. A $ is a valid identifier start character, but you should only use $ for "mechanically generated" identifiers. See the java language spec http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8

Answer (score 3):

The dollar sign is used by the compiler for inner classes. I thought it would be strange to manually make classes/files with those names though: As far as I know it's a compiler thing.